# How do I add 30min to a time while using materialize CSS?

Tags: javascript, forms, datetime, time, materialize

I am using materialize CSS's time picker.

[image]

Now unfortunately for me, it is a **text input** and I can get the value but I dont know how to add 30 min to a text input.

This is what I tried.

```
  const start_time_inp = document.getElementById('start_time').value;
  const end_time_inp = document.getElementById('end_time');


  function changeendtime() {
    console.log(start_time_inp.getTime() + minutes*60000);
  }
```

but I cant make it work, because this is not a time input. Can you help me out?

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="text" id="start_time" name="start_time" class="timepicker Vwhite-text" placeholder="Start Time*" onchange="changeendtime()">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="text" id="end_time" name="end_time" class="timepicker Vwhite-text" placeholder="End Time*">
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am terrible at JS.